# Command prompt isn't working when launched from "Run" dialog or system32 folder

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Whenever I start Command prompt using `cmd` in "Run" prompt (obtained using  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), it's stuck at this:

[image]

Neither launching from **C:\WINDOWS\system32** works. However, it works when I launch it from Start Menu.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  . Follow with SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart and test

Comment: @John That didn't fix the issue. However I found the answer on Microsoft Community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that command prompt launched using "Run" dialog only ran when legacy console option was enabled. I fixed the issue after disabling **Use Separated Foreground** and **Use Separated Background** in **Terminal Colors** under **Terminal** tab in the properties.

**Source:** [Command prompt only works in legacy console mode - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/command-prompt-only-works-in-legacy-console-mode)